# How to remove private code before publishing?

Tags: c, publish

We have a medium-sized C codebase that provides an API for using our hardware products. We provide the source for this API so that customers can compile it into whatever environment they choose. It's important that the source is legible and easily navigated as many people do just that. We don't obfuscate it in any way.

In our code we have a number of functions and sections that are for internal testing only, stuff like wrapper methods, low level checks, etc. None of it is particularly interesting nor harmful in any respect but we don't really want people using them or getting confused about what they are. This has happened numerous times before despite having warnings in the code about using them.

Is there any tool or method by which we can filter out these sections before publishing the source?

Right now we use a custom method with comments, however it's hard to parse and maintain:

```
/* $if : INTERNAL : some comment */
debug_code();
/* $endif : INTERNAL */
```

I've looked at using `#ifdef` and the preprocessor but there doesn't seem to be a way to preprocess specific defines/macros and not the whole file at once. I would only want the specific blocks preprocessed (and therefore removed) and not all the defines and in the code.

EDIT: From my comment below, the stuff we would like to remove from the published code should not be located in separate files. Like wrappers, we prefer to keep those next to the functions they wrap to make it easy to find. Other times we have detailed comments about internal implementation that we want in the code for our reference but don't want others seeing it.

Comment: I'd give a chance to [GPP](http://math.berkeley.edu/~auroux/software/gpp.html). You can feed it with source files and - like C preprocessor - it'll give you processed output files. Its syntax is customizable then it may be instructed to remove `debug_xyz();` calls. Well, if you're _limited_ to remove debug function calls (with a well-defined signature) even a _simple_ Perl script may help.

Comment: Another useful tool is coan (http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php), which is still actively maintained (although apparently it currently doesn't compile cleanly on Mac OS X, if that is a concern).

Comment: It's tedious, but you could keep that internal code outside your modules in the first place and `#define` it in macro's in an external module/header. When building for internal you `#include` the internal version of these macro's, when building for others, you include a version with dummy macro's.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I checked out GPP, thanks for the link. It's doable but maybe a tiny bit overkill. Also it seems the last update was 10 years ago! Currently we use a python script to filter out internal stuff, it's just that editors can't fold our special syntax and maintenance of the scripts is a bit of an issue.

Comment: @rici I think coan may be the simplest to understand and easiest to implement here. Luckily we don't put #defines in the source files, so I think (based on the online docs) we can filter out specific sections by defining 'internal' macros and leaving all the others undefined. If you make an answer for this question I'll accept yours.

Comment: @eresonance: OK, added an answer. I have no connection with `coan` (other than being a reasonably satisfied user on occasion) so I don't have any problem putting it in an answer.

Comment: checkout border gateway protocol, it seems to be what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One tool I've found useful for applications like this is [coan](http://coan2.sourceforge.net/index.php), which is still actively maintained (although apparently it currently doesn't compile cleanly on Mac OS X, if that is a concern).

Coan is designed for code analysis and it can perform quite a few tasks which you probably don't need. As long as you don't explicitly `#define` the preprocessor macros which surround the code to be removed, you should be able to just `-D`efine or `-U`ndefine as appropriate.

Coan wants to keep the code consistent, and can evaluate preprocessor macros so as to correctly evaluate and possibly eliminate preprocessor conditionals. Even if you don't ask it to do the evaluation, it will normally interpret and simplify `#ifdef` blocks if the definition is visible. Even that behaviour can be altered with the `--no-transients` option, but it will emit a warning.

Answer (score 2):

You should have put your testing code in different files, even better using proper testing frameworks (like Google Test or CUnit). In that case, removing the tests would have been matter of just removing some files. I suggest to go towrads heavy refactoring to isolate testing code in specific files.

Comment: Similar to what I said in my comment above.

Comment: Yes, a more structured approach to developing would of saved a lot of time now. I realize that it's easy for us to say this but it's worth looking into completely overhauling the code and where and what is being placed where. Time well spent!

Comment: Thanks for the comment. We actually do that already, we have a test suite with a swig-based python wrapper that allows us to test all of our methods via python. We do not include this in the published archives.

The 'testing' stuff I mentioned in my question cannot be moved to separate files. Like wrappers, we prefer to keep those next to the functions they wrap to make it easy to find. Other times we have detailed comments about internal implementation that we want in the code for our reference but don't want others seeing it.

In-place removal is what we require here.

Answer (score 1):

The two options I would consider are `awk` and `m4`.

Something like `sed '/\/\* *\$if/,/\/\* *\$endif/d'` (untested) would delete all the lines between the comments you've illustrated.  That's a bit crude, but if it's sufficient, it's simple enough that it would probably be robust.

If you need something more elaborate, then `m4` would be worth looking at (see the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/m4/) of the GNU implementation of m4).  `M4` is largely *for* this sort of text manipulation job.  It's powerful, but that includes being powerful enough that you can tie yourself in knots with it (don't get carried away!).  Hint: the default quote characters in `m4` are left and right quote -- this isn't always convenient, and so the `changequote` function can be a lifesaver; thus `changequote([[,]])` makes `[[square brackets]]` the quote characters.